# Swagger in my spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0

What is **paramType** in the annotation

```
 @ApiImplicitParams( {
 @ApiImplicitParam( name = RestRequestHeader.XAUTHTOKEN, value = RestRequestHeader.VALUE, required = RestRequestHeader.REQUIRED, dataType = "string", paramType = "header" ) } )
```

What are the different values **paramType** can take and what are its functionalities? I have tried searching in google, but could not find any satisfying solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use documentation?

http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/apidocs/com/wordnik/swagger/annotations/ApiImplicitParam.html#paramType()

Answer (score 0):

You can check out 
[OpenAPI specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/1.2.md#524-parameter-object).

Possible values are `"path", "query", "body", "header", "form"`

**Note that the values MUST be lower case.**

- `path` paramtype suggests that the type of implicitparam goes into requestUri
- `query` means it is a type of url query params
- `body` denotes it should be read from request body (payload)
- `header` denotes the parameters coming in request header
- `form` denotes field corresponds to the form parameter.

**UPDATE**

Basically what you are saying is correct you can use `form` or `query` also in case of GET method. But according to OpenAPI specs if your parameter type is **File**, the consumes field MUST be **multipart/form-data**, and the paramType MUST be **form**. `form` should be used also when content-type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

For path you can use if your RequestParam mappings looks something like `@RequestMapping("/test/{id}")`  here you can use `path` as your paramType to define `id` param. In this case your url will contain dynamic values
lets say

For e.g. a url 
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43342169/edit contains (43342169) which is post id going as param in url itself these type of params are path param.

Comment: can you please elaborate more on `path` and what I understand is `form` parameters will go as query parameters if the action is GET. So Waht is the difference between `query` and `form`?

Comment: I marked it, but I don't have enough reputation to reflect my vote

Comment: @Sandesha No issues :)